# How do I prove theta(log n)=o(log n)?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I'm solving a question from CLRS where we need to prove that (ceil(lg lg n))! is polynomially bounded.

```
Let g(n)=(ceil(lg lg n))!
lg(g(n))=lg((ceil(lg lg n))!)
        =theta(ceil(lg lg n) * lg (ceil(lg lg n))) [since lg(n!)=theta(n * lg n)
                                                    and replacing n by ceil(lg lg n) here.]
        =theta((lg lg n) * (lg lg lg n))  ----(1)  [since ceil(n)=theta(n)
                                                    and replacing n by (lg lg n) here.]
```

**Now if I can prove that theta(lg n)=o(n)**

```
=>theta(lg lg lg n)=o(lg lg n)
=>theta((lg lg n) * (lg lg lg n))=o((lg lg n) * (lg lg n))
                                 =o((lg lg n)^2)
                                 =o(lg^2(lg n))
                                 =o(lg n)  ----(2) [Polylogarithmic functions grow 
                                                    slower than
                                                    polynomial functions.
                                                    =>log^b(n)=o(n^a)
                                                    =>log^2(log n)=o(logn^1)
                                                    =>log^2(log n)=o(log n)]

From (1) and (2) we have log(g(n))=o(log n)
=>g(n)=o(n^a) that is g(n) is polynomially bounded.
```

**The only problem I'm facing is to prove that theta(lg n)=o(n). 
Please help!**

Answer (score 2):

Hint: take derivatives on both sides and show that the derivative on the left tends to 0 (i.e. is smaller than any constant for n big enough). The derivative on the right is constant. Use that to show that the right side will always outgrow the left side for n big enough.